# Translating Oracle right outer join to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm fairly new to SQL and I'm trying to translate some Oracle commands to SQL Server. The issue lies with converting the following right outer join:

```
where
   SOURCE_FORMATS.LOC_SIMPLE_ENTITY_ID = FILEFORMAT_INTERNAL_SIGNATURES.LOC_FILEFORMAT_ID (+)
```

As far as I can understand in SQL this has to be represented in the "from" section to be something like:

```
from
   SIMPLE_ENTITIES "SOURCE_FORMATS"  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN FILEFORMAT_INTERNAL_SIGNATURES
on SOURCE_FORMATS.LOC_SIMPLE_ENTITY_ID = FILEFORMAT_INTERNAL_SIGNATURES.LOC_FILEFORMAT_ID
```

Is this logic correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, and it's the *better* solution, too, since it conforms to the ANSI standard of how to write JOIN's - I would prefer this over the Oracle format any day.

Comment: No, I think first query is a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Oracle has supported ANSI outer join syntax for well over a decade now (since version 9.0 in 2001).  The old `(+)` syntax was what Oracle had before the ANSI join syntax was established.  I believe other RDBMSs at that time had similar proprietary syntax such as `*=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pre-ANSI Oracle syntax for outer join, the (+) is used against the table which is expected to be deficient, not against the table to be preserved.

So:

```
select * from t1, t2 where t1.col1 = t2.col2 (+)
```

is the same as

```
select * from t1 left join t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2
```

Comment: Good answer and I like the simple example. Thanks

Comment: Thanks all for pointing out this is a left join, not a right join